# kml to kml conversion with XSL

Tags: kml, convert, xml, xsl

I have a simple KML file witch I get with ogr2ogr where all placemark are 2D polygon like this one :

```html
<Placemark>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
       <color>ff0000ff</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
       <fill>0</fill>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
  <ExtendedData>
    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#BATI">
      <SimpleData name="HAUTEUR">5</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData>
  </ExtendedData>
  <Polygon>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>
          5.210274804171726,45.193994541274471,0 5.210273193448314,45.193992448578285,0 5.210244307501982,45.194002928913058,0 5.210153551080012,45.193930862320109,0 5.209984563035429,45.194038696922476,0 5.210076592373608,45.194110738456011,0 5.210146416870383,45.194072424624984,0 5.210176223631215,45.194092352007594,0 5.210274804171726,45.193994541274471,0
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

I would like to convert all of them to polygon with extrusion. The value of z coordinates is defined by the value of "HAUTEUR" extended data. Here it's 5 meters:

```html
<Placemark>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>ff0000ff</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
      <fill>0</fill>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
  <ExtendedData>
    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#BATI">
      <SimpleData name="HAUTEUR">5</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData>
  </ExtendedData>
  <Polygon>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>
           5.210274804171726,45.19399454127447,5 5.210273193448314,45.19399244857829,5 5.210244307501982,45.19400292891305,5 5.210153551080012,45.19393086232011,5 5.209984563035429,45.19403869692248,55.210076592373608,45.194110738456,5 5.210146416870383,45.19407242462499,5 5.210176223631215,45.19409235200759,5 5.210274804171726,45.19399454127447,5 
         </coordinates>
       </LinearRing>
     </outerBoundaryIs>
   </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

I thought that a XSL Stylesheet is the best and the easiest way to process the conversion but I can't figure how to start.
Has someone ever managed it?